# Converting from Hexadecimal to Denary in Python

Tags: python

How would I go about doing this? I don't know where to start. I assume you would multiply the value of the bits by its place value, but not sure how you'd create code for this. I've done hexadecimal to binary but not binary to denary.

Comment: OMG, not again, do your own homework... I'd recommend start reading a Python or CS tutorial/book...

Comment: This is not homework. No need for the rude replies. I am just intrigued.

Comment: @JoeBarry while KurzedMetal comment was uncalled for, you did not put enough effort in your question. You have to do some research on your own before posting. And you need to show the things you tried. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask for more information

Answer (score 3):

http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#int

Python's `int` function creates base 10 numbers, and lets you supply the base of the variable you are feeding.

`x = int('FF', 16)`  is the same as `x = 255`

Comment: Well, strictly speaking `int` creates numbers from strings, and only when you *print* these numbers will they be turned into the base 10 string representation.